# Can Akka.NET and Original Akka communicate Using Remoting?

Tags: akka, akka.net

Can Akka.NET and Original Akka communicate Using Remoting?

In other words can Akka be used to connect a JVM and CLR in a system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue on the akka.net Github https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/132 Describes several reasons why this doesn't work:

> 1) We use different serializers for user messages, Akka uses the
>   default Java serializer, Akka.NET uses Json.NET. This could be solved
>   by using e.g. google protobuf, serializers are pluggable.
>
> 2) Helios (akka.net transport) and Netty (akka transport) are most
>   likely not compatible on a binary level, both do use a 4 byte length
>   prefix to frame messages (AFAIK, @Aaronontheweb ?) but my guess is
>   that they won't play nice together.

And perhaps more fundamentally:

> The big issue here is this: Java is BigEndian, .NET is LittleEndian -
>   at least, it's LittleEndian on most Windows systems. Endianness in
>   .NET can vary from platform to platform, which is true for Mono too.

It also appears there is not much appetite for solving the issues:

> I'm wondering how useful full protocol compatibility really is. So
>   even with the issues you point out aside, imagine having to constantly
>   maintain versions that work with specific Akka versions. You never
>   know when something is going to change. Seems like it would be a
>   nightmare to maintain.
>
> I just don't see a compelling use case for wanting to run Akka.NET and
>   Akka fully meshed. I would think that you normally just need to
>   provide some limited functionality on the other side. It can be useful
>   to maintain the same design pattern (actor model) across both systems,
>   but full compatibility I'm not so sure.

So it is unlikely to work any time soon.

Comment: That's a shame, would help a lot in porting c# projects into scala. thanks for the info.